# C macro gives compile time error

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to use macro to expand a function. So I wrote the following code:

```
#define INIT ( T ) \
    struct T * init##T() { \
    struct T * obj  = ( struct T *)malloc( sizeof (struct T )); \
    return obj; \
} \
```

I call the macro using the following :

```
INIT (mystruct);
```

error ::

> error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
>       warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]

I want to basically write generalized macro that accepts any structure, allocates space to an object of that structure and returns a value for the same.

Comment: Can you provide the actual result of gcc -E ?

Comment: ( T ) struct T * init() { struct T * obj = ( struct T *)malloc( sizeof (struct T )); return obj; } ( mystruct );

Comment: Why are you returning a value if it's not a function-like macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grammar for the definition of function-like macros in 6.10 (1) says:

> `# define` *identifier lparen identifier-list<sub>opt</sub>* ) *replacement-list new-line*
>
> *lparen:* a ( character not immediately preceded by white-space

There must not be whitespace between the macro name and the opening parenthesis in the macro definition (there may be whitespace between them in macro invocations, however).

Thus you do not define a function-like macro but an object-like macro, expanding to

```
( T ) struct T * ...
```

Remove the space:

```
#define INIT( T ) \
    struct T * init##T() { \
    struct T * obj  = ( struct T *)malloc( sizeof (struct T )); \
    return obj; \
}
```

and it will work.

Comment: Remember that the restriction on whitespace between the macro name and the `(` applies only to the macro definition, not to invocations of the macro. `INIT (mystruct);` is still valid.

Comment: Yes, that should probably be emphasised.